# Accessing the ids from the JSON files to be used in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to access the elements in the nested array for my file given as :

```
[
 {
    "RT": 2.8196,
    "name": "xyz",
    "mz": 405.2996521,
    "MS2": [
        [
            "101.6111298",
            "354.3106689453"
        ],
        [
            "103.3474808",
            "342.7608032227"
        ],
        [
            "105.6327438",
            "353.7338867188"
        ]
   ]
 }
]
```

I want to access the individual elements of MS2 for my application in d3. How can it be done?

Comment: Parse you content in file using var obj = JSON.parse(text);

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you name the variable "result" so you have:

var result = [ { "RT": 2.8196, "name": "xyz", "mz": 405.2996521, "MS2": [ [ "101.6111298", "354.3106689453" ], [ "103.3474808", "342.7608032227" ], [ "105.6327438", "353.7338867188" ] ] } ];

You can access the individual arrays in MS2 using:

```
jQuery.each(result[0]['MS2'], function(member){
    // do something with member...
});
```

Ofcourse you will need the Jquery library for this.

Comment: Thanks. I know It can be done using jQuery but I wanted to incorporate it in my code for scatter plot. I am not getting how to access the MS2 values since they have to be on the x and y axis.

Comment: If you can post some code as to what exactly you are trying to do, I can help

Comment: var xValue = function(d) { return (d.MS2);}, // data -> value
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]), // value -> display
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));}, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

// setup y
var yValue = function(d) { return d.MS2;}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

Comment: var xValue = function(d) { return (d.MS2);},
var yValue = function(d) { return d.MS2;},

this is the code in question, right ? You need to return member[0]'s for x and member[1]'s for y as per my code, right ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That's what I want !

Comment: Okay. If you need the whole array of x's in one return, perhaps you can use .each to create an array and then return it ? Will that work in your case ? Something like `jQuery.each(result[0]['MS2'], function(member){ array.push(member[0]); return array });`. A similar function can be written for y to push member[1].